# How to avoid multiples downloads of the same JNLP?

Tags: java, jnlp

I had a app based on JNLP, but every time when the user click in JNLP file, the new Download happen, and the file is greater than 80mb.

I read all documentation, the file is signed with a trust cert from DigiCert.

Any ideias?

Comment: The jar is downloaded over and over? Web server time stamps?

Comment: How is the server providing the application file(s)?  I’m guessing they aren’t static content.